# Python get anchor text and href value but only within a specific div class

Tags: python

I have the following Python code that scrapes ALL anchor text links and corresponding href values from every link on a specific url:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/my-url"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.text, '-', link.get('href'))
```

It works fine BUT i only want it to crawl href links that are in a specific DIV with a class. For example, i only want it to crawl links within a div with a class of 'main-page-wrapper':

```
<div class="main-page-wrapper">
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
<a href="/help">Help</a>
</div>
```

So the result is:

```
Contact - /contact
Help - /help
```

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Use something like `for link in soup.select('div.main-page-wrapper a'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something as follows:

```
divs = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'main-page-wrapper'})

for div in divs:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print(a.text, '-', a.get('href'))
```